# Using Multiple Gleam of Authority

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Following up on a recent post,

"I am looking for some clarification on the card Gleam of Authority. The wording on the card is

```
Enchantment - Aura

Enchant Creature

Enchanted creature gets +1/+1 for each +1/+1 counter on other creatures you control.
```

There is also a tap ability to bolster and vigilance.

The problem I'm seeing with adjusting continuously, is if multiple Gleam of authorities are played. Does this create an infinite loop?

Comment: Why is there an infinite loop? The +1/+1 given by the Enchantment isn't a +1/+1 counter, so it doesn't boost other Gleams of Authority.

Comment: As the answers on the linked question say, +1/+1 counters are completely different from "gets +1/+1" effects, so Gleam of Authority doesn't "count" its own effect.