# Double Gleam of Authority interaction

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If 2 copies of [Gleam of Authority](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gleam%20of%20Authority) are on the board would that mean that +1/+1 counters would bounce back and fourth to infinity?

Comment: You can create links to card by typing [mtg:Card Name]

Comment: Note that [this other question](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23640/using-multiple-gleam-of-authority) is the same as this one, and is already closed as a duplicate of the question I linked.

Comment: So if one creature had a 1/1 counter and a 2nd creature had gleam of authority the 2nd creature would get a counter and a third creature with GOA would also get a counter but the 2nd creature wouldn't get a counter for the third creature getting a counter? If that makes sense lol

Comment: No, Gleam of Authority doesn't add counters (except with its Bolster ability), it just grants +1/+1 without using counters, so if the Gleam of Authority is removed from the creature it loses the +1/+1, whereas if it added counters the creature would not lose them when Gleam of Authority is removed.

Answer (score 6):

**No, it would not.**

You misunderstood how [Gleam of Authority](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gleam%20of%20Authority) works. Gleam does not place +1/+1 counters on the creature it enchants, it simply gives it +1/+1 for each counter on other creatures. The difference is that counters remain on the permanent they are placed on while the +1/+1 granted by an enchantment disappears when the enchantment is destroyed.